# Selenium tests work perfectly on my local but fail on virtual machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, virtual-machine, s

I have a suite of automated tests made with Selenium and Python with 359 tests. When I run them on my computer, they always passs, but in my company, they set up a virtual machine and when they run it there, there are always about 15/25 tests that fail (different tests every time) The failure is always timeout and all the waiting time is set to 60 seconds. The virtual machine has 8gm of RAM. I think it should be enough.
Any idea of what could be going on?